# Select column of other row in parameterized statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, parameterized-query

I am a beginner in SQL, and I was having some trouble with special characters like parentheses and asterisks in user generated data. So far, I have mostly been using a lot of ad hoc methods of getting rid of these characters and they work well enough. Based on what I have read, I think paramaterized queries might be a more systematic way of getting around some of the problems that I have.

I have following query:

```
insert into midstep (street)(select street from addresses limit 10)
```

The column street in the table addresses has a lot of parantheses, asterisks etc. The code above works as expected. What I want to do is something like this:

```
prepare midstreet (text) AS insert into midstep (street)(select $1 from addresses limit 10);
 execute midstreet ( street from addresses);
```

However, when I enter in that code I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "from"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 29
```

I have tried a bunch of variations on this code and read through the documentation on [Prepare](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-prepare.html#SQL-PREPARE-EXAMPLES) and [Execute](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-execute.html) but always get error messages. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I am using postgresql 9.3 on and my os is Ubuntu. Please ask if you need any more information to help!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a parameter in your case, as you get your values using a sub-query. As a matter of fact, you cannot know the needed values on server-side. Parameters like that are needed if and only if you have some values defined on application level and you want to pass them to the database.

Comment: If parameterizing isn't the way to go, what would you reccommend to get rid of parantheses and asterisks? I will be passing this data into a geocoder that doesn't know how to deal with parentheses and asterisks.

Comment: When you are querying inside the RDBMS, there is no danger of SQL injection. SQL injection is a possible danger when you are querying something and adding parameters from outside the RDBMS. If you are having a value, like I'm hungry, you will not get errors because of the '. The problem is when you generate your query and the result looks like this: select * from users where username = ''; delete from users;'